# Building complex Eloquent query using belongsToMany relationship, foreign table and whereIn()

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

In a Laravel 5 app, I have 5 tables - users, books, authors, followers and activity_feeds.

Users can follow authors and a book can have several authors.
When a book is made, an activity_feeds entry is made that references the book_id.

I need to build an eloquent query to get a collection of activity_feeds for each users, to iterate over in their home page activity feed.

My Book model includes

```php
public function authors()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Author')->withTimestamps();
  }
```

The activity_stream table looks like this (with example data)

```
id (1)
user_id (3)
type (New Book)
book_id (18)
created_at etc
```

and my User controller includes

```php
public function feedItems()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ActivityFeed');
  }

public function userFollowings()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'follower_id', 'subject_id')->withTimestamps();
  }

public function authorFollowings()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Author', 'followers', 'follower_id', 'author_id')->withTimestamps();
  }
```

My current query (which isn't working), contained in the User model is

```php
public function getactivityFeedsAttribute()
{
   $userFollowings = $this->userFollowings()->pluck('subject_id')->toArray();
   $authorFollowings = $this->authorFollowings()->pluck('author_id')->toArray();

   $userFeeds = ActivityFeed::whereIn('user_id', $userFollowings)
                             ->orwhereIn('book_id', function($query){
                               $query->select('id')
                                ->from(with(new Book)->getTable())
                                ->whereHas->authors()
                                ->whereIn('id', $authorFollowings);
                                })
                              ->get();
  return $userFeeds;
}
```

$userFollowings and $authorFollowings are working fine.

I'm not sure I'm using the correct syntax for data[book_id] to pluck the book id from the activity_feeds row, and I'm really not sure if I can nest a table look up or use $query like this.
It also seems VERY complicated. Am I might be missing something much more straight forward?

In the blade I am calling like this

```html
@forelse ($user->activityFeeds as $activityFeed)
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      {{ $activityFeed->user->firstname }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      {{ $activityFeed->type }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
@empty
    No activity yet
@endforelse
```

Which works if I just query 'ActivityFeed::whereIn('user_id', $userFollowings)'

Comment: This data attribute... what is it? Are you keeping it in the DB as an array? a string?

Comment: I was saving it to the DB like this - $newActivityFeed->data = ‘{“book_id:”’ .$book->id. ‘}”; - but I’m not sure if I can cheat like that.

Comment: so data is a string. If you want to save a json, you could use a `json` column. Personally, I've never had the need to do so though. The important thing is that data is a `string` so you can't treat it like an array in your `whereIn` clause.

Comment: I've changed the data column in activity_feeds table to a simple integer and sending just the book ID to it, for now, as I don't need anything else right now. Have updated the code above. I'm now getting the error "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$whereHas"

Comment: You're not using `whereHas` correctly. Instead of `->whereHas->authors()`, use  `->whereHas('authors')` and if you need to query the relationship `authors`, pass a closure to `whereHas`. `->whereHas('authors', function($query) use ($authorFollowings) { $query->whereIn('id', $authorFollowings); })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll rewrite the query in an answer because comments aren't very legible.

```php
public function getactivityFeedsAttribute()
{
    $userFollowings = $this->userFollowings()->pluck('subject_id')->toArray();
    $authorFollowings = $this->authorFollowings()->pluck('author_id')->toArray();
    $books = Book::whereHas('authors', function ($query) use ($authorFollowings) {
        // Have to be explicit about which id we're talking about
        // or else it's gonna throw an error because it's ambiguous
        $query->whereIn('authors.id', $authorFollowings);
    })->pluck('id')->toArray();

    $userFeeds = ActivityFeed::whereIn('user_id', $userFollowings)
    ->orwhereIn('book_id', $books)
    ->get();

    return $userFeeds;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this IGP. I'm now getting this error - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'has' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `activity_feeds` where `user_id` in (3) or `book_id` in (select `id` from `books` where `has` = authors)) . Strangely, if I remove the closing get() the error goes, but obviously it returns nothing.

Comment: My mistake. `whereHas` is a method from the Eloquent Query Builder so it couldn't be used like that. I reworked the answer so it gets the books before the `$userFeeds` query.